# I got Solstice for a comment on the 22nd?

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2014

I just got the Solstice Winterbash hat here on Meta Stack Exchange. Checking my activity, I have not posted or commented yesterday (the 21st). I do, however, have an upvoted comment today. That comment was posted on the 22nd in UTC.

I'm happy to have gotten Solstice here, but it wasn't really deserved. Is this a bug, or is Stack Exchange being generous?

Comment: Oops, shame on me, @ProgramFOX! First part there says it... 13 hours after the UTC date passed.